# XAMPP FTP server error?

Tags: macos, ftp, localhost, xampp

XAMPP 1.7.3 for Mac does not let me run the FTP component.

> XAMPP Cannot run FTP while another FTP
>   server is using Port 21.

I'm not running anything else FTP related. I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.4.

Comment: I think I would find a TCPview equivalent for Mac and see what else is using port 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Mac OS X's built in FTP server running? (Check under Options... in File Sharing in the Sharing Preference Pane)

Comment: Good call, Chealion!